# Help understanding the use of tetrahedrally arranged vectors to compute the gradient of a function

Tags: vector-analysis, inner-products, surfaces, vector-fields, divergence-operator

As a long-time user of the free, open-source raytracer POV-Ray, I'm trying to understand some of the source code used to compute and perturb surface normals.  The method uses the evaluation of 4 points, offset from a point on the surface in a regular tetrahedral arrangement.
https://news.povray.org/povray.general/message/%3C5c45e632%241%40news.povray.org%3E/#%3C5c45e632%241%40news.povray.org%
3E

I have only found one mention of this method:

https://iquilezles.org/articles/normalsSDF/

which only provides a brief summary of how it works.

> The four sampling points are arranged in a tetrahedron with vertices
> k0 = {1,-1,-1}, k1 = {-1,-1,1}, k2 = {-1,1,-1} and k3 = {1,1,1}.
> Evaluating the sum "m = Sum ki * f (p + h*ki)"
> (see equation in link) on those four vertices
> produces some nice cancellations that results in m = Sum ki (f (p + h*ki) - f(p))
> (see equation in link) which are four directional derivatives, meaning we can rewrite
> the sum as ....

m = Sum ki * Del ki * f(p) = Sum ki (ki * Del f(P))
and
mx = Sum kix Del ki f(p) = Del f(p) (dot) Sum kix*ki = Del f(p) * <4, 0, 0>

And then normalizing this result gives the surface normal at the point of interest.

I would like to know the origin of this method, hopefully in a reference.
I would like to understand how summing the product of 4 vectors with 4 scalar function results gives the cancellations and "directional derivatives".
(I have a sneaking suspicion that it may be related to calculating the divergence of the vector field defined by the tetrahedron, but that's math that's *just* a step ahead of anything that I formally studied and am sufficiently familiar with to work out on my own.)
However, I haven't been able to independently come up with a way to operate on the terms that results in anything that would cancel out and give me what appears to be a new f(p) term as shown in that next step.

I tried to implement the method myself in code
http://news.povray.org/povray.pov4.discussion.general/message/%3Cweb.6552db6d61b9f4951f9dae3025979125%40news.povray.org%3E/#%3Cweb.6552db6d61b9f4951f9dae3025979125%40news.povray.org%3E
but it doesn't seem to fully work - some of the normals seem to point in the wrong direction.

Finally, it's unclear to me how such a method can be implemented to perturb the normals of a smooth surface to simulate a an actual surface deformation using only a scalar function result to control the normal pattern.  The way I'm thinking about it is that I can take a surface normal and make it point anywhere around a sphere centered on that point on the surface - which requires 2 dimensional spherical coordinates.  A scalar value has no directional component to direct which way to perturb the normal of the surface.

Thanks you for any insights, leads, or explanations that you can offer,

- Bill